# TensorFlow GridLSTM Example

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

## Main Question

There are two implementations of GridLSTMs:

1. `tf.contrib.rnn.GridLSTMCell`
2. `tf.contrib.grid_rnn.Grid1LSTMCell`

Using either in a `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` gives me errors, and essentially my question is this:
*Are there any implementations, repositories etc that make use of either cell with the recent tensorflow API?*

I am aware of [this implementation](https://github.com/phvu/grid-lstm-tensorflow/blob/master/char_rnn/model.py), but it focuses on seq2seq and I cannot apply it to dynamic_rnn or static_rnn.

#### Current Progress and Smaller Questions

If I were using `tf.contrib.rnn.GridLSTMCell` then my code would look like this:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

rnn_cell_sizes = [512, 512]

cells = []
for size in rnn_cell_sizes:
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.GridLSTMCell(num_units=size)
    cells.append(cell)

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells)
input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, sequence_length, fft_size * feature_vector])

tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=input_placeholder, dtype=tf.float32)
```

This will return an error like so:

`ValueError: Must specify num_frequency_blocks`

This is because num_frequency_blocks is required. I can see that it is a list, but I can't work out what it's for!

Alternatively, I could use some cell from `tf.contrib.grid_rnn` such as `tf.contrib.grid_rnn.Grid1BasicLSTMCell`.

My code then becomes something like this:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

rnn_cell_sizes = [512, 512]

cells = []
for size in rnn_cell_sizes:
    cell = tf.contrib.grid_rnn.Grid1BasicLSTMCell(num_units=size, output_is_tuple=True)
    cells.append(cell)

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(cells)
input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, sequence_length, fft_size * feature_vector])

tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=input_placeholder, dtype=tf.float32)
```

This will then throw a large stack trace and an error like so

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------

-----
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in zeros(shape, dtype, name)
   1438       shape = tensor_shape.as_shape(shape)
-> 1439       output = constant(zero, shape=shape, dtype=dtype, name=name)
   1440     except (TypeError, ValueError):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape)
    207       tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(
--> 208           value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
    209   dtype_value = attr_value_pb2.AttrValue(type=tensor_value.tensor.dtype)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py in make_tensor_proto(values, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    379     # exception when dtype is set to np.int64
--> 380     if shape is not None and np.prod(shape, dtype=np.int64) == 0:
    381       nparray = np.empty(shape, dtype=np_dt)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in prod(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
   2517     return _methods._prod(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype,
-> 2518                           out=out, **kwargs)
   2519 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _prod(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     34 def _prod(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
---> 35     return umr_prod(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     36 

TypeError: __int__ returned non-int (type NoneType)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-f9b0851a2255> in <module>()
     11 input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, sequence_length, fft_size * feature_vector])
     12 
---> 13 tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=cell, inputs=input_placeholder, dtype=tf.float32)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py in dynamic_rnn(cell, inputs, sequence_length, initial_state, dtype, parallel_iterations, swap_memory, time_major, scope)
    612         swap_memory=swap_memory,
    613         sequence_length=sequence_length,
--> 614         dtype=dtype)
    615 
    616     # Outputs of _dynamic_rnn_loop are always shaped [time, batch, depth].

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py in _dynamic_rnn_loop(cell, inputs, initial_state, parallel_iterations, swap_memory, sequence_length, dtype)
    775       loop_vars=(time, output_ta, state),
    776       parallel_iterations=parallel_iterations,
--> 777       swap_memory=swap_memory)
    778 
    779   # Unpack final output if not using output tuples.

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in while_loop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants, parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory, name)
   2814     loop_context = WhileContext(parallel_iterations, back_prop, swap_memory)  # pylint: disable=redefined-outer-name
   2815     ops.add_to_collection(ops.GraphKeys.WHILE_CONTEXT, loop_context)
-> 2816     result = loop_context.BuildLoop(cond, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
   2817     return result
   2818 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in BuildLoop(self, pred, body, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
   2638       self.Enter()
   2639       original_body_result, exit_vars = self._BuildLoop(
-> 2640           pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
   2641     finally:
   2642       self.Exit()

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py in _BuildLoop(self, pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
   2588         structure=original_loop_vars,
   2589         flat_sequence=vars_for_body_with_tensor_arrays)
-> 2590     body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
   2591     if not nest.is_sequence(body_result):
   2592       body_result = [body_result]

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py in _time_step(time, output_ta_t, state)
    760           skip_conditionals=True)
    761     else:
--> 762       (output, new_state) = call_cell()
    763 
    764     # Pack state if using state tuples

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py in <lambda>()
    746 
    747     input_t = nest.pack_sequence_as(structure=inputs, flat_sequence=input_t)
--> 748     call_cell = lambda: cell(input_t, state)
    749 
    750     if sequence_length is not None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/grid_rnn/python/ops/grid_rnn_cell.py in __call__(self, inputs, state, scope)
    192                  new_output, new_state, True)
    193       _propagate(conf.priority, conf, self._cells,
--> 194                  c_prev, m_prev, new_output, new_state, False)
    195 
    196       # collect outputs and states

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/grid_rnn/python/ops/grid_rnn_cell.py in _propagate(dim_indices, conf, cells, c_prev, m_prev, new_output, new_state, first_call)
    627   else:
    628     cell_inputs = array_ops.zeros([m_prev[0].get_shape().as_list()[0], 0],
--> 629                                   m_prev[0].dtype)
    630 
    631   last_dim_output = (new_output[-1]

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in zeros(shape, dtype, name)
   1439       output = constant(zero, shape=shape, dtype=dtype, name=name)
   1440     except (TypeError, ValueError):
-> 1441       shape = ops.convert_to_tensor(shape, dtype=dtypes.int32, name="shape")
   1442       output = fill(shape, constant(zero, dtype=dtype), name=name)
   1443   assert output.dtype.base_dtype == dtype

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, preferred_dtype)
    834       name=name,
    835       preferred_dtype=preferred_dtype,
--> 836       as_ref=False)
    837 
    838 

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor(value, dtype, name, as_ref, preferred_dtype, ctx)
    924 
    925     if ret is None:
--> 926       ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
    927 
    928     if ret is NotImplemented:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _tensor_shape_tensor_conversion_function(s, dtype, name, as_ref)
    248   if not s.is_fully_defined():
    249     raise ValueError(
--> 250         "Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: %s" % s)
    251   s_list = s.as_list()
    252   int64_value = 0

ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (?, 0)
```

I don't really mind how I get there it would just be nice to get a gridlstm working in TensorFlow! Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Did you try passing in an actual batch_size into your input placeholder? I was getting a similar error when my input shape started with [None, ] so I changed it to the actual batch size and it worked. But now I'm getting a different dtype error...